# A smooth function instead of a piecewise function

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions

I want to find a smooth function approximating f(x) as best as possible:

\begin{equation*}
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x & \text{if } x \le a,\\
a & \text{if } x > a.
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

as a  smooth function ($a$ is a positive constants and x is a positive real number). $f(x)=\sqrt[n]{x}$ has a similar trend, but not good enough. What is best alternative function for the piecewise one.

[image]

Comment: Did you mean "curve" instead of "cure"? Otherwise I'm afraid we're anatomically unadapted for that...

Comment: Anyway, your function, as written, is *already* continuous everywhere...

Comment: What do you exactly mean when you say "I want to represent it as a curve"? Your function is what it is, no more and no less. You should make clearer what "to represent" means for you.

Comment: Your function is continuus (and hence a curve) iff $c=a$.

Comment: Let's see if I'm understanding you well enough: what you want is to find a smooth function approximating $f(x)$ "as best as possible" (whatever that means for you). Is this right? In that case you may modify your function on an arbitrarily small interval around $x=a$ to make it smooth.

Comment: You may use the Weierstrass or the Poisson transform.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_transform
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice class of functions which "approximate" your continuous example is given by the sigmoids:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function

Unfortunately your "best alternative function" concept is not well defined, as pointed out by Hagen von Eitzen. I would try (if this is your exact problem!) at least to work with a fixed "error" $a-g(a)$ at the point $a$, while searching for a smooth candidate $g$ approximating your function $f$.

Comment: you are welcome. You have some freedom in choosing the sigmoid you need; in applications the logit and probit functions are widely used. It could be interesting to modify their parameters and visualize their positions w.r.t. the given $f$. You could even introduce a sequence of smooth functions g_n converging pointwise to your given $f$.

Answer (score 8):

As I said in one of my comments you can modify $f(x)$ in a neighbourhood of $x=a$, say $(a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon)$, for $\varepsilon>0$ as small as you wish. In that small interval you want to change your function by some other smooth function $g(x)$ satisfying the following conditions: $g(a-\varepsilon)=a-\varepsilon$, $g(a+\varepsilon)=a$, $g'(a-\varepsilon)=1$, $g'(a+\varepsilon)=0$. These conditions ensure that $g$ glues well (smoothly) with $f$.

If my computations are not wrong a function satisfying the conditions above is $$g(x)=-\frac{1}{4\varepsilon}\left(x^2-2(a+\varepsilon)x+(a-\varepsilon)^2\right).$$

Then a smooth function approximating $f$ would be
$$
f_{\varepsilon}(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ccl}
x &\mbox{if}& x\leq a-\varepsilon\\-\frac{1}{4\varepsilon}\left(x^2-2(a+\varepsilon)x+(a-\varepsilon)^2\right)&\mbox{if}&  a-\varepsilon\leq x\leq a+\varepsilon\\
a&\mbox{if} & x\geq a+\varepsilon
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Notice the subscript $f_\varepsilon$ indicating the dependence on the parameter $\varepsilon$. The smaller you take the parameter, the better the approximation (since you're modifying $f$ in a smaller interval).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually I want to avoid a piecewise function.

Comment: Don't the second derivatives fail to match up?  The second derivative of the first piece at  $x = a-\epsilon$  is 0, while the second derivative of the second piece at that point is  $-1/4\epsilon$ .

Answer (score 3):

Consider the weighting function $h(x)=exp(5(x-a))/(1+exp(5(x-a))$, which takes values close to 0 for $x<<a$ and close to 1 for $x>>a$, [plot it to check this statement] Now approximate your $f(x)$ weighting $x$ and $a$, like in 
$$
g(x)=x(1-h(x))+ah(x)
$$
Intuitively, $h$ allows you to switch from $x$ to $a$ (or any other constant or function, for that matters) around $x=a$, with a speed that depends on the arbitrary coefficient 5, which can be seen in the definition of $h$. Increase it to improve the fit.

See an example for $a=3$ in the picture below.[image: Approximation of $f$]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a smooth function $f\colon[0,\infty)$ such that $f'(0)=1$ and $f(x)\to a$ as $x\to\infty$, you can try
$$ f(x)=\frac{2a}{\pi}\arctan \frac {2x} {a\pi}$$
or 
$$ f(x)=\frac{x+ax^2}{1+x^2}.$$
In order to say what is "best", some measure of quality should be specified.