# Smoothing piecewise linear functions

Tags: smooth-manifolds, piecewise-continuity

I have a piecewise linear function which is continuous.  I am looking for a good way to "smooth" the function at the boundary points.  Ideally, I would like a solution that's similar to A. Bellmunt's here:

[A smooth function instead of a piecewise function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/410840/a-smooth-function-instead-of-a-piecewise-function)

However, in my case, the slopes between each need not be $0$ or $1$, rather, they can be arbitrary.  Futher, I require that the "smoothed" section lie above each piece of my piecewise linear function.

What is the simplest such construction that exists?

Comment: Your requirement that the smoothed graph has to lie above the original graph $f$ at all points will cause ugly goose-pimples at the peaks of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

If your output exhibits seasonality, you can use additional dummy variables to obtain a smoothed single linear function, something like [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/108877/capturing-seasonality-in-multiple-regression-for-daily-data). This will get rid of piecewise linear functions and the discontinuity in derivatives therein.